# Can we use swift along with objective - c in Xcode 6 beta?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6

Can we use both swift (.swft) and objective c (.h .m) in same xcode project ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page 1 of [Apple's Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-XID_0):

> Swift feels familiar to Objective-C developers. It adopts the readability of Objective-C’s named parameters and the power of Objective-C’s dynamic object model. **It provides seamless access to existing Cocoa frameworks and mix-and-match interoperability with Objective-C code**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. You might want to take a look at [this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, except there are few limitations. For example Swift specific features are not accessible from Objective-C. For example Generics, Tuples , Nested Types etc.